# python - iterate over all pairs of consecutive items with gaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iterator

Given a list:

```
mylist = [1,6,4,9,2]
```

I would like to return all pairs of consecutive items within a window.
For example, if I want pairs of 3 consecutive items, I could do:

```
items=3
for x in range(0,len(mylist)-items+1):
    print(mylist[x:x+items])
```

Which outputs:

```
[1, 6, 4]
[6, 4, 9]
[4, 9, 2]
```

This assumes the window size is also 3, so it's only scanning 3 indexes at a time.
If I instead want to return all pairs of 3 consecutive items in a window of 4, I would want:

```
[1, 6, 4]
[1, 6, 9]
[1, 4, 9]
[6, 4, 9]
[6, 4, 2]
[6, 9, 2]
[4, 9, 2]
```

Is there a simple method to produce these pairs?

Edit to add to Alex's answer below:
I ended up using combinations to identify the indexes, then only selecting the indexes starting with zero, like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
def colocate(mylist,pairs=4,window=6):
    x = list(combinations(range(window),pairs))
    y = [z for z in x if z[0]==0]
    for item in y:
        print(item)
```

Comment: "all pairs of 3 consecutive items in a window of 4" is completely add odds with the definition of "consecutive"

Comment: _consecutive items with gaps_ ? Perhaps it might help if you could take a step back and explain what you need this for.

Comment: sorry if consecutive isn't the right vocabulary, I'm not looking for combinations. The order matters, but the items don't have to be perfectly next to each other. So it's more like ordered permutations inside a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly easy way to do it is to think about it in terms of the index rather than the list items itself. Start with:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.combinations(range(len(mylist)), 3)
```

This gets you all the possible index triple combinations in a list with the length of your list. Now you want to filter them to exclude any where the last index is 4 or more away from the first:

```
list(filter(lambda seq: (seq[-1] - seq[0]) <= 4, itertools.combinations(l, 3)))
```

This gets you the indeces you want. So now you can get the triples you need based on the indeces:

```
[[mylist[i] for i in seq] for seq in filter(lambda seq: (seq[-1] - seq[0]) < 4, itertools.combinations(l, 3))]
```

which produces:

```
[[1, 6, 4], [1, 6, 9], [1, 4, 9], [6, 4, 9], [6, 4, 2], [6, 9, 2], [4, 9, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

"Combination" is a concept in math related to your question. It does not care about "window of 4" though.

```py
from itertools import combinations

l = [1,6,4,9,2]

for combination in combinations(l, 3):
    print(combination)
```

```
(1, 6, 4)
(1, 6, 9)
(1, 6, 2)
(1, 4, 9)
(1, 4, 2)
(1, 9, 2)
(6, 4, 9)
(6, 4, 2)
(6, 9, 2)
(4, 9, 2)
```

I'm curious why do you want to have a window of 4.

Maybe there is a better way to solve your task at hand?

Comment: i want to count the number of times items appear close to each other, not exactly side by side. So provided some sliding window size, find all pairs that are "in order" in a given pair size.

Answer (score 1):

This gets pretty close. There will be some duplicates produced, but that's what `set(...)` is for at the end... should give you some ideas anyway.

```py
from itertools import combinations, islice, chain

# from itertools examples
def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result

mylist = [1,6,4,9,2]

set(chain.from_iterable(combinations(w, 3) for w in window(mylist, 4)))
```

```
{(1, 4, 9), (1, 6, 4), (1, 6, 9), (4, 9, 2), (6, 4, 2), (6, 4, 9), (6, 9, 2)}
```

Comment: This is basically exactly what I was in the middle of writing. The `window` recipe selects the input to `combinations`, `combinations` gets all ordered non-contiguous selections from within each window. You could preserve order of first appearance for each result by changing `set(...)` to `list(dict.fromkeys(...))` (use `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys` prior to Python 3.6), though that assumes that you don't want to see a duplicate even if it comes from unrelated windows.